# Display full names in Neo4J Browser

Tags: neo4j-browser

In Neo4J Browser, the Graph is shown with Edge labels truncated, with dots (...).

I would like to display the Edge (Relationship) labels fully, without the triple dots (...).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try running these queries and for the last query it should show you the relationship name as "KNOWS".

**Query 1:**

```
Create (p:Person { name: "Abc" , place: "Usa"})
```

**Query 2:**

```
MATCH (p:Person) WHERE p.name = "Abc" 
CREATE (p1:Person { name: "xyz", place: "Canada" }), (p2:Person { name: "pqr", place: "England"}), (p)-[:KNOWS {since: 2001}]->(p1),(p1)-[:KNOWS {rating: 5}]->(p2)
```

**Query 3:**

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:KNOWS]-(p1) WHERE p.name = "Abc" RETURN p, p1
```

Abc - KNOWS -> xyz

Update:
I am not sure this is appropriate or not but I just tried giving long label for a relationship.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xd8m.png)

Comment: I know how to create vertices and edges. My point is that a long Edge label will get truncated. e.g. if my Edge label is "SUPER_LONG_EDGE_LABEL" in the Neo4J Browser it might get shown as "SUPER_LON..."